# C++11 - Error in calculating mode in a vector of numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, calculator, mode

I'm working on a program that, given a list of values (`double`s) from an input file, sorts them in ascending order and calculates the `mode`, and print the result in an output file. This is what I came up with so far.

What it should do is assign the mode to the `x`th element of the vector, the one that produces the greater value for `current`, but when I run this program the mode is always equal to the last element of the vector.

I just can't figure out what mistake I'm doing, because in my mind it seems perfectly logical.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream iFile("inp.txt");
    if(!iFile)
    {
        cout << "Error input!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    ofstream oFile("out.txt");
    if(!oFile)
    {
        cout << "Error output!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double data;
    vector<double> list;

    while(iFile >> data)
    {
        list.push_back(data);               //put the elements in a vector
        sort(list.begin(), list.end());     //and sort them in ascending order
    }

    for(int m = 0; m < list.size(); ++m)    //this is just
    {                                       //to verify
        oFile << list[m] << endl;           //that the elements
    }                                       //are listed in order

    int current = 0;
    int previous = 0;
    int mode = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); ++x)        //select an element of the vector
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < list.size(); ++y)    //match it against all the other elements of the vector
        {
            if(list[x] == list[y])              //if they're of equal value
            {
                ++current;                      //add 1 to variable "current"
            }
        }

        if(current > previous)                  //if "current" > "previous"
            {
                mode = list[x];                 //set the element "x" (from the first for) of the vector "list" to be the new mode
                current = previous;             //and set current to be the new previous    
            }

        current = 0;                            //reset current to 0
    }

    oFile << "\nmode: " << mode << endl;        //output "mode"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your mode calculation is very inefficient.  Imagine if there are 1000 numbers -- your nested `for` loop would iterate a million times, if there were 10000 numbers,the loops would iterate a hundred million times -- in other words, `O(n*n)`.  For a sorted list, the mode can be calculated in a single loop in one pass through the data.  Even for an unsorted list, the mode can be calculated more efficiently.

Comment: Apart from the issue which is (I think) answered below, I am very suspicious of the concept of a "mode" when applied to a set of **`double`** values.  If you have some idea of the range of the numbers, then divide them into suitable bins, and count the number in each bin.  (A `std::map` might be a suitable structure to hold the counts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
previous = current;
```

instead of

```
current = previous;
```

in the last `if`, or `previous` is ever zero and the last `x` (matching with itself when `y` is equal to `x`) generate a `current` greater than `previous` (that is zero).

OT: look at this `while`

```
while(iFile >> data)
{
    list.push_back(data);               //put the elements in a vector
    sort(list.begin(), list.end());     //and sort them in ascending order
}
```

There is no need to sort the vector after every single insertion. I suggest you to add in `list` all the content of the input file and, after, sort the vector. Only one time, only after the last insertion.

Something like

```
while(iFile >> data)
{
    list.push_back(data);  //put the elements in a vector
}

sort(list.begin(), list.end()); //and sort them only one time
```